# How do I only filter the results for custom graphs on the HTML Report for Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I've tried using the following under the definition for custom graph but it filters the entire report:

```
## Custom graph definition
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.classname=org.apache.jmeter.report.processor.graph.impl.ResponseTimeOverTimeGraphConsumer
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.title=Login Response Time Comparison
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.property.set_Y_Axis=Response Time (ms)
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.property.set_X_Axis=Over Time
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.property.set_granularity=${jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity}
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.property.setSampleVariableName=label
jmeter.reportgenerator.graph.custom_mm_hit.property.setContentMessage=Message for graph point label
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Run 1 Login|Run 2 Login)(-success|-failure)?$
```

How can I provide separate filtering for each custom graph?

For instance, if there are 3 transactions being monitored but I would like to split out one on its own Response Time Over Time custom graph while keeping all 3 on the original Charts dropdown Response Time over Time graph.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting):

> `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter`
>
> Regular Expression which Indicates which graph series are filtered in display.
>
> Empty value means no filtering.
>
> Defaults to empty value.

So you can apply a filter only to all HTML charts.

The only workaround I can think of is storing particular transaction response time into a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) and plot it as a [custom chart](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)

Alternative solution would be uploading your test results to [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) analysis service where you can apply whatever filters you want on the Composite Timeline Analysis tab

[image]